# Adding html select to dialog box causing unwanted css whitespace

Tags: css, impromptu

I am using a plugin called jquery impromptu to create dialog's on my web site. I've noticed that when you try and add a html select to the dialog it causes some unwanted whitespace around the border of the dialog.

None of the other html form controls that I've tried so far have the issue. It's only the html select.

There is something css related that I need to fix to resolve this but I can't figure it out. Can someone please help me with this.

```js
var textAreaStr = '<div>' + 
       '<label>Note<textarea id="registerFlagNote" rows="7" cols="30">      </textarea></label><br/>'+
       '</div>';

var selectHtmlStr = '<div>' + 
      '<label>Close flag?<select id="registerFlagClosedOpenInd">' +
      '<option value="no" selected>No</option>'+
      '<option value="yes">Yes</option>'+
      '</select></label>'
      '</div>';  
// try text area by itself
//var htmlStr = textAreaStr + '<br/>';
// try select by itself
//var htmlStr = selectHtmlStr + '<br/>';
//try both
var htmlStr = textAreaStr + selectHtmlStr + '<br/>';

var statesdemo = {
 state0: {
  html:htmlStr,
  buttons: { Cancel: false, Next: true },
  focus: 1,
  submit:function(e,v,m,f){
   $.prompt.close();
  }
 }
};

$.prompt(statesdemo);
```

```css
div.jqimessage div textarea,
div.jqimessage div select{
 display:block; 
}

/*div.jqi {
    padding: 0 !important;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-impromptu/6.2.1/jquery-impromptu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-impromptu/6.2.1/jquery-impromptu.js"></script>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect element to the class `.jqi`

You would see this

```
div.jqi {
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 90%;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

Simply just remove `padding:7px;`

Comment: Hi,Although this answer helps hide the problem it does not fix the root cause. I've updated my snippet above to have a html area. I'd like you to try the html area by itself first, then try both the html area and the select box. And uncomment the padding 0px override I have created in the css. You will see that the root cause is still there when you add the select. Without the select the dialog looks perfect. Hope this makes sense. New fiddle here ... (http://jsfiddle.net/richieriviere/tf8xorsm/2/)

Comment: Brian Just wondering if you saw my previous comment. For some reason I can't seem to tag you in a comment. @Brian

Comment: @Richie, sorry for the late reply, I can't understand what you mean though, you may edit your question to clarify things up. :)

Comment: Hi Brian. in the last fiddle I added (2 comments prior to this one) it has a text area and a drop down. Modify it just to show the text area only first and see how it looks. It looks perfect. Then add the drop down and observe how we see unwanted whitespace. My question is why does that appear only when you add the drop down. And just for good measure in the css section of the fiddle I tried your suggested result. You still have some unwanted whitespace. Does that make sense?